# wnsow.setResizable not working in NWjs

Tags: javascript, nw.js, nwjs

window.setResizable(false) is not working in NWjs. window.enterFulscreen() is also giving undefined by NWjs inspector.

I am on windows10 64 bit pc, having latest NWjs setup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create a new window and get it
    // Open URL with default browser.

    window.enterFullscreen()
    // nw.Shell.openExternal('https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js');
     // window.setResizable(false);
</script>
```

Do I need to import some module and how?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I forgot to `var win = nw.Window.get();`
Thanks

Comment: you should mark this as the correct answer so that the question is answered ;)

Comment: In the package json u can set to kiosk mode